# Tensorflow graph building mechanism

Tags: tensorflow, graph

When I tried to understand the underlying mechanism of the following tensorflow graph building code, I was confused about 3rd and 4th lines. I assumed that in side the +operator overloading , adder_node builds references to both a and b. However when the adder_node is executed on line 4, what would be the mechanism to distinguish  a(a: 3) and b(b:3). Lets say, if the placeholders are filled with values and if the adder_node has references to both a,b  why do we have to pass these parameters again.

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
adder_node = a + b 
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b: 4.5}))
```

Comment: By "pass these parameters again", do you mean giving a `feed_dict` to `sess.run` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `a`, `b`, and `adder_node` are nodes in a graph.

The `adder_node` knows to take the values inside `a` and `b` and to perform an operation on them. The graph looks like this:

[image: Your graph]

When you perform `sess.run(adder_node)` you're telling tensorflow to evaluate the value of `adder_node` (aka to perform all the dependent operations and perform the operation of `adder_node`).

In order to calculate `adder_node` tf will calculate the value of `a` and `b`, which are placeholders, so their operation is to take the values from the feed_dict. So, every time you need to compute `adder_node` you will have to provide values for the placeholders, so they can get computed.

`{a: 3, b: 4.5}` is not specifically passing parameters to `adder_node` but passing parameters to the graph.

You can have this code which passes a, b, and c as parameters to the graph, and adder_node add z an c:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
c = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = a + b 
adder_node = z + c
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b: 4.5, c: 1.5}))
```